# How to uninstall OpenJDK13 from Windows 10 (not showing in Control panel)?

Tags: java, windows, uninstallation

I wanted to uninstall OpenJDK13 from Windows 10. But OpenJDK is not listed/showing-up in the control panel.

How could I uninstall?

Thankyou

Comment: Just delete the folder and remove any related environment variables, if you set them

Comment: You can simply delete the directory and install another version. To check where it is, open the command prompt (cmd, not powershell) and type `where java`.

Comment: Thank you, worked well.

Answer (score 0):

on windows:

1: remove jdk folder or rename the foler

2: remove all env vartiable and path from environment system

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the environment variables
2. Restart your computer
3. Delete the JDK source folder

Answer (score 0):

open **command prompt**
write command **where java**
remove the **directory**
check again by running command **java --version**